# Referencing wrong table

Tags: sql, field

Working on a script for our phone routing, and I am coming on this issue where whenever I try to query the "Extension" field on the "User" table, it is telling me extension doesn't exists on the "name" entity.

```
SELECT 
u.Phone "Owner Phone",
u.Extension,
u.id "Owner User ID",
l.Phone "Lead Phone",
l.IsConverted


From 
Lead l,
User u
JOIN user u
on u.id = l.ownerid 

Where 
    (l.Phone = CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',3,3), ') ', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',6,3), '-', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',9,4)) OR l.Phone_Secondary__c = CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',3,3), ') ', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',6,3), '-', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',9,4)) OR l.Co_Client_Phone__c = CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',3,3), ') ', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',6,3), '-', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',9,4)))
```

That is my current code, and below is the error I am getting.

```
INVALID_FIELD
SELECT Lead.Owner.Phone,Lead.Owner.Extension,Lead.Owner.id
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:25
No such Column 'Extension' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a please append the '__c'
```

I have verfied the field I am pulling is correct, and if I just do

```
Select Extension From user
```

It works fine, and I am query results.

Comment: Your initial SQL code joins the table `User` twice giving it the same alias both times!  Did you really intend that?  If so, explain why.  If not, I think that without the redundant table might work.

Answer (score 0):

As MAP said, the issue is with your join. If you remove the comma after your alias for the lead table, the query should execute correctly:

```
SELECT 
u.Phone "Owner Phone",
u.Extension,
u.id "Owner User ID",
l.Phone "Lead Phone",
l.IsConverted


From 
Lead l
JOIN user u
on u.id = l.ownerid 

Where (l.Phone = CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',3,3), ') ', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',6,3), '-', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',9,4)) OR l.Phone_Secondary__c = CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',3,3), ') ', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',6,3), '-', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',9,4)) OR l.Co_Client_Phone__c = CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',3,3), ') ', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',6,3), '-', SUBSTRING('%ANI%',9,4)))
```

Comment: Sadly, even with the removal of redundant "user u", I am still getting the same error. Any idea why it might be saying that it isn't found on the name table?

Comment: Does the query successfully run if you remove u.Extension from the select statement?